# angular is not detecting created servcie

Tags: angular, angular6

I have created a service fetch-data, and I am calling it's instance inside dashboard component, but it is showing the import as undefined.

I have tried to create this service in different locations but has no success, also a service created in the same directory is getting detected.

This is the service that I created

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { BaseService } from "./base.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class FetchDataService extends BaseService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    super(http, "metrics/");
  }

  getDailyData() {
    return this.get(
      "daily?property_uuid=new"
    );
  }
}
```

this is the component in which I am calling it

```
constructor(
    private info: SidebarInfoService,
    private fetchService: FetchDataService
  ) {
    this.fetchService.getDailyData().subscribe((val: any) => {
      this.dateData = this.correctDayData(val.payload.data);
    });
}
```

I am getting this error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getDailyData' of undefined
    at DashboardComponent
```

**BaseService**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core"; 
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http"; 
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" }) 
export class BaseService { 

     baseUrl: string = ""; 

     constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private url: string) { 
        this.baseUrl = environment.serverURL + this.url; 
     } 

     get(url) { return 
        this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + url); 
     } 

  }
```

Comment: How you are importing the FetchDataService...?

Comment: Not the error, but you'd usually don't fetch data in the constructor but in ngOnInit

Comment: can you share code of `BaseService`?

Comment: @ganesh045 in the imports at the top of the file (not shown here)

Comment: @Iftifaz Tax here is the code
```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { environment } from "src/environments/environment";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class BaseService {
  baseUrl: string = "";
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private url: string) {
    this.baseUrl = environment.serverURL + this.url;
  }

  get(url) {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.baseUrl + url);
  }
}
```

Comment: @Injectable on BaseService is not required unless you are using it as a service on its own.

Comment: Same code is working here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-agx97a (except the http request as I don't have your server). Please review your app according to that stackblitz. Or provide your own stackblitz with the error to let us help you better

Comment: just avoid the extending service from another service.. I think there is no point of extending one service to another where both are singleton and root scoped ;))

Comment: Try this stackblitz, like @ganesh045 said, I would avoid using this base service as its not adding any benefits. Open the console on the stackblitz showing u lorem Ipsum --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/service-test-angular

Answer (score -2):

did you provide it in your app module ?? if you didn't go to app.module.ts and in the providers array put your service .

Comment: cause of ```@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})```he doesnt have to, its creating a singleton across the whole app. BTW your Answer should be a comment.

Comment: it's working (but if I keep this file in some other directory). thanks. But I already added "providedIn:root" so did I really have to add it in the providers?

Comment: No u dont have to. TBH I dont see whats going wrong here. Can u create a minimal stackblitz?

Comment: Ahh, delete the @Injectable on the baseService

Comment: as sagat mentioned you don't have to if you are using ```@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })``` here are the docs [link] (https://angular.io/guide/providers#providedin-and-ngmodules)